# How to make table cell shrink according to the content?

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

How can I make the table with 2 columns (cells) look like this:

- First cell is shrink according to the content
- The other cell fits the rest of the table (wider than both contents together)

Example:

```
<table style="width: 500px;">
   <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I need the table to look like this:

```
.___________________________________________________________________________.
| foo | bar            <a lot of space here>                                |
|_____|_____________________________________________________________________|
                           500 px total width
```

Notice: I don't know the width of "foo" so I cannot set "50px", "10%" or something like that.

Comment: set a width like 10px.... e.g. `<td width="10">foo</td>`

Comment: Well, it's right at the bottom of my post. I don't know the width of the cell so I can't set it manually. I need the browser to shrink accodring to the content ("foo" in my example, but it may be "foooooooooo" which is too long for 10px).

Comment: even if you set a 10px width, the cell will grow according to content. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7X4XT/2/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can set the `width` of the second cell to `100%`

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td class="grow">bar</td>
   </tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
table { width: 500px; }
.grow { width: 100%; }​
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scumah/bqptb/) out.

Comment: This only works if `table-layout` is set to `auto` on the table.  This is the default, but it's common to set `table-layout` to `fixed`, which will cause the 100% value to be taken literally (the cell will span the entire table, and all cells will overlap).

Comment: when I resize the fiddle window containing the html output, it does not grow at all.

Comment: <table style='white-space:nowrap'> shrink it to the content. Don't set width on the first cell!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is what I used. As an aside, I know you didn't intend this (and probably don't care since this question and answer has nothing to do with Tailwind), but `grow` reminded me of Tailwind's `grow` attribute for flexbox. I had to do a double take to see that it was setting the width to full.

Comment: Hey @kevlar! Sorry I just saw this comment :( When I answered Tailwind didn't even exist, this is a veeeery old question :P

Comment: @scumah I just noticed the timestamp... wow!

Answer (score 106):

Set the width to anything near zero, to shrink it, then set the white-space to nowrap. Solved.

```
td {
width:0.1%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, a width of `0` doesn’t have any effect, but your `0.1%`  appears to be a nice hack to achieve this.

Comment: personally, I went with width: 1px. great idea Nat!

Comment: @SnailCoil The 1px doesn't work when other columns are using percentages that are adding up to less than 100%. My columns can be dynamically hidden so they can't always add to 100% (and didn't want to recalculate). Nat's answer works great and fixes a problem I've had for over a year.

Comment: to save others the trouble, this seems to have the same problem with `table-layout: fixed` as [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413365/how-to-make-table-cell-shrink-according-to-the-content#comment28477786_11414056)

Comment: This is buggy as hell and works who knows how. With column width of 100% when I do this on the last cell of the row, it starts to overflow outside the table itself.

Answer (score 5):

Set this:

```css
td {
    max-width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Nice solution for compact data, but doesn't work so well if you happen to require longer content to wrap in one cell

Answer (score 1):

If the total size of the table is 500 pixels and will not pass, put `td{max-width: 500px;}`; If the minimum value is 500 pixels, `td {min-width: 500px;}`; Look this [exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/5jSZE/).