# Align characters to fixed width in html

Tags: html, css

I have an html table layout where I need to align numeric strings but some do not exist. Simple example below

Example1: OK

```
01234567890123456789
                4321
              437652
```

Example2: OK

```
0123456789
      4321
    437652
```

Example3: **NOT** OK (as gap on left)

```
      0123456789
            4321
          437652
```

- Max 20 characters
- Characters always 0 to 9

Originally I right aligned the data in a column but my client doesn't like it as if there is an example with less than 20 characters then it leaves a big gap on the left.

I've tried padding the missing charatcers with `&nbsp;` but it's not even close [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpv2L07j/2/)

Is there a way to give each character a fixed width in html or a better way to do this?

Comment: can we modify the HTML? like say add a wrapper div?

Comment: What's your table structure?

Comment: It's a 2 column table only where some rows wrap into second column. The main structure is this but this only has 2 rows https://jsfiddle.net/wpv2L07j/2/

Comment: @NarenMurali - yes. Actually the data is already within span tags to colour them.

Comment: What am I missing here? What you want sounds like the default style for a table. https://jsfiddle.net/ac56q127/ Of course if 1 of the numbers is 20 chars wide, then all cells have that width. But that's correct, right? When using a second column and 100% table width: https://jsfiddle.net/ac56q127/1/

And in general, you could use a monospace font to fix it with `nbsp` but then you'll need to figure out the largest number before printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution will be to stick to your original idea of `text-align:right`, since you do not need to go through much hassle with this idea, you can although add a small concept that will shrink your column to fit the contents of the column, please refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413365/how-to-make-table-cell-shrink-according-to-the-content) from where I got the idea, so we can set the second column to 100% width and the first column will shrink to fit the contents. Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

```css
.popUpBox1Table td {
  text-align: right;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.popUpBox1Table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #FFFFB0;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.popUpBox1Table td:empty:after {
  content: "\00a0";
}

.rightalignPopUp1 {
  text-align: right;
}

.redPopUp1 {
  color: red;
}

.bluePopUp1 {
  color: #002060;
}

.greenPopUp1 {
  color: #385623;
}

.brownPopUp1 {
  color: #833c0b;
}
.grow { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<body>

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" class="popUpBox1Table">
    <tr>
      <th>values</th>
      <th class="grow">dummy</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bluePopUp1">7</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="bluePopUp1">3</span></td>
      <td class="rightalignPopUp1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span>
        <span
        class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span>
          <span
          class="bluePopUp1">7</span><span class="redPopUp1">6</span><span class="bluePopUp1">3</span></td>
      <td class="rightalignPopUp1"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: @pathDongle Does this answer help you? Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

To me this is a clear example where flexbox could help you. What you need to do is create a container wrapper for those entries and set it as

```
.container { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

By doing this you’re putting your elements one on each line. Now what’s called the main axis will be the vertical axis because you have a column setup.

After this you need to tell your elements to align to the flex end ( meaning the right side in your case ).

So if you do

```
.container { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

It will push the elements to the right side

You can have a look [here](https://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html) for a quick reference